# Impact of timezone change during sql server migration

Tags: sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019, windows-server-2019

We are migrating from our legacy SQL Server 2017 on Windows 2016 host to SQL Server 2019 on Windows 2019. In above migration the bigger change has been the difference in timezone between legacy and new build Windows host. Earlier we used to have mix of CST, EST and PST servers being built but now everything is standardized under UTC. Me being DBA, trying to understand possible impact with above change. Few questions here:

1. What impact if any is expected for queries querying with getdate(), will they impact DB queries as time is now in UTC?
2. AD team said they can force application to send ET at their end but how will it handle sql querying when landing to DB?
3. All the databases in question here uses partitioned tables with partition functions as date ranges and lot of ad-hoc queries are done on read replica. Will there be impact or change to partitions?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. What impact if any is expected for queries querying with getdate(), will they impact DB queries as time is now in UTC?

From a performance perspective?...none.

> 2. AD team said they can force application to send ET at their end but how will it handle sql querying when landing to DB?

They will need to query against the data using the same time zone it's set to, or you'll need to come up with a solution that automatically converts the datetimes passed in from the application to UTC before querying the data (e.g. making the calls procedure driven).

> 3. All the databases in question here uses partitioned tables with partition functions as date ranges and lot of ad-hoc queries are done on read replica. Will there be impact or change to partitions?

They'll be based on UTC moving forward, and should be queried against with UTC datetimes according.